# Using a custom function in Twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

In my template I want to output the server timezone.

My template has something like

```
{{ getservertimezone }}
```

Then in the `services.yml` config for that bundle I have

```
my.twig.extension:
    class: My\WebsiteBundle\Extensions\Twig\SomeTemplateHelper
    tags:
           - { name: twig.extension }
```

And my `SomeTemplateHelper` looks like

```
namespace My\WebsiteBundle\Extensions\Twig;

class SomeTemplateHelper extends \Twig_Extension
{

    public function getFilters() 
    {
        return array(
            'getservertimezone'  => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'getServerTimeZone'),
        );
    }

    
    public function getServerTimeZone()
    {
        if (date_default_timezone_get()) {
            return date_default_timezone_get();
        } else if (ini_get('date.timezone')) {
            return ini_get('date.timezone');
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'some_helper';
    }
    
}
```

But I can't call this method unless it's used like a filter: `{{ someval | getservertimezone  }}`; is there a way to just do a straight `{{ getservertimezone() }}` call?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use `getFunctions()` instead of `getFilters()`

```
public function getFunctions()
{
    return array(
        new \Twig_SimpleFunction('server_time_zone', array($this, 'getServerTimeZone')),
    );
}
```

Twig filters are used to filter some value.

```
{{ "some value" | filter_name_here }}
```

Btw, you can define both filters and functions in the same class.

Comment: Twig_Function_Method is deprecated use Twig_SimpleFunction instead. I open an issue on the symfony doc https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/3275

Answer (score 6):

Instead of `getFilters`, override `getFunctions` and use `Twig_Function_Method` instead of `Twig_Filter_Method`.

Answer (score 6):

In the newer versions of Twig he should be using Twig_SimpleFunction instead of Twig_Function_Method and Twig_SimpleFilter instead of Twig_Filter_Method, since Twig_*_Method are deprecated (I am using Twig v. 1.24.0 along with Symfony 2.8.2)

Answer (score 2):

## Symfony ^2.6 - twig ^1.38

See example below

---

#### AppExtension.php

```
namespace Your/NameSpace;

class AppExtension extends \Twig_Extension {

    public function getFilters() 
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('cdn_asset_filter', array($this, 'cdn_asset_filter')),
        );
    }

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig\TwigFunction('cdn_asset_function', array($this, 'cdn_asset_function')),
        );
    }


    public function cdn_asset_filter($path) 
    {
        return "https://cdn.example.com/$path";
    }


    public function cdn_asset_function($path) 
    {
        return "https://cdn.example.com/$path";
    }
}
```

---

#### view.html.twig

```
// Filter

<img src="{{ 'path/to/image.png'|cdn_asset_filter }}">

// result : <img src="https://cdn.example.com/path/to/image.png">


// Function

<img src="{{ cdn_asset_function('path/to/image.png') }}">

// result : <img src="https://cdn.example.com/path/to/image.png">
```

---

#### app/config/services.yml

```
services:
    my_global_filters_and_functions:
        class: Your/NameSpace/AppExtension
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

---

This is how i used custom functions in Twig in one my old projects, i don't know if it's a best practice, but it worked for me.

---

Resources : Twig Documentation - [Extending Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/1.x/advanced.html)