# Twig - How to randomise items in the array and loop them?

Tags: php, arrays, twig, twig-filter

How can I randomise items in the array and loop them?

```
{% for item in article.resources|shuffle|slice(1) %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

I get this error:

> Unknown "shuffle" filter in "partials/content.twig" at line 30.

If I use [random()](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/random.html):

```
{% for item in random(article.resources|slice(1)) %}
```

Nothing is returned.

Any ideas?

**NOTES:**

I don't want to use PHP btw.

Comment: define a twig function called `shuffle` and use php shuffle in this function. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13277444/using-a-custom-function-in-twig

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

Comment: And keep in mind `php shuffle` works with a reference and has no return value.

Comment: `I don't want to use PHP btw.` then you are not get it done. If twig not have something like `shuffle`, you have to create a function in twig (that is written in php). And `random` will give you one random entry, you cant loop this, because `random` may give the same result in next iteration

Comment: Why don't you want to do it in the controller?

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions  
where should i store this custom function then? and how i can inject it to twig system?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Twig [Array Extension](http://twig-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/array.html) already has a `shuffle()` filter ([based](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig-extensions/blob/master/lib/Twig/Extensions/Extension/Array.php) on PHP [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php))

Comment: Here is a working link: http://twig-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/array.html

Comment: Thanks, I fix the anwser!

Answer (score 4):

Do something like that:

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$function = new Twig_SimpleFunction('shuffle', function ($array) {
    shuffle($array);
    return $array;
});
$twig->addFunction($function);
```

read more about it here

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#functions

Comment: No thing, but `Twig Array Extension` is the better way ;) didnt now it

Comment: got it sorted by installing the extensions. thanks! :-)

Answer (score 3):

I used the Twig [Array Extension](http://twig-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/array.html), to make use of `|shuffle`. On my installation the extension wasn't loaded.

Added this to my config/services.yml, under services:

```
services:
    twig.extension.array:
                class: Twig_Extensions_Extension_Array
                tags: [twig.extension]
```

Then you can use:

```
{% for item in items|shuffle %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question but since it seems that the Twig ArrayExtensions are depreciated I thought of providing an alternative way without any extensions:

```
{% for item in article.resources|sort((a,b) => random(-1,1)) %}
  ...
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you will have to remove slice part of it.

Try this code and let me know if this works.

```
{% for item in random(article.resources) %}

{% endfor %}
```

You would probably like to keep some check in your for loop to ensure random is not returning same item twice.