# I have a gallery of images in Grav/Twig and want a few of them to be displayed on homepage but randomly

Tags: twig, grav

Currently using `page.find('/folder_name').media.images` to extract **images** and setting limit in for loop. But no way to randomize them. And setting limit in for loop is I believe not a good way of doing it. Could anybody help?

Here I am asking for gallery. The suggested method works on articles but not on media collection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twig - How to randomise items in the array and loop them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40629390/twig-how-to-randomise-items-in-the-array-and-loop-them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got success. I used randomize function as follows to random my image collection with slice to limit it to only 50 images.

```
image_album = page.find('/folder_name').media.images|randomize()|slice(0,50)
```

This works for me and gave desired result.