# using random function but it's displaying duplicates

Tags: php, twig

I am using the random function in twig and it is randomizing the images I need but it is repeating the logos. How can I make it so that the images are not repeated but are still randomized?

this is my code

```
{% set listItems = block.logos %}
    {% for item in listItems %}
        {% set item = random(listItems) %}
{% endfor %}
```

block.logos refers to the logos that i have implemented in block called logos. There is a field in the block in which i can add multiple images/logos in the block. i have about 20 logos.

Ive attached a photo for reference of the issue.
[image]

Comment: What do you mean with "It's repeating the same logo's". Are you display multiple logo's per `listItem` or are you using the "same" logo in different `listItems`?

Comment: Im displaying multiple logos per listItems. But for some reason some of the logos are being repeated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Twig - How to randomise items in the array and loop them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40629390/twig-how-to-randomise-items-in-the-array-and-loop-them)

Comment: @DarkBee i already tried the answers in those questions. I was able to fix it by creating my own wp function instead of trying to solve it in twig

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP array_rand function.

`array_rand($listItems, 1);`.

If your array is a key value array and your need the value use the returned key as index for get the image.

```php
$index = array_rand($listItems, 1);
print_r($listItems[$index]);
```

Comment: Don't think this will help OP in any way, this does basically does the same as `random` inside twig anyway. OP has to extend more on the question

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly: you have a list of images, and want to display them in a random order without displaying the same image twice.

Ideally you could implement a custom twig function based on the php function: [shuffle](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php). However for a quick solution, you could randomly sort an array.

```
{% set listItems = block.logos|sort((a, b) => random() <=> random()) %}
{% for item in block.logo %}
    {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```